# PhpMyAdmin is showing some Warnings

Tags: phpmyadmin

My phpMyAdmin is showing some warings and I don't know how to fix them. I have changed the location of phpMyAdmin. Before the location was `www.website.com/phpmyadmin` and I have changed to `www.website.com/phpmadmin`.

It was working without problems but some days ago i have done "do-release-upgrade" and I have got some errors. I am running on Ubuntu 15.

What can I do to fix this problems? What files should I have to edit?

> Warning in ./libraries/Util.class.php#516  file_exists(): open_basedir
>   restriction in effect. File(doc/html/index.html) is not within the
>   allowed path(s):
>   (/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/)
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./libraries/Util.class.php#516: file_exists(string
>   'doc/html/index.html') ./libraries/Util.class.php#540:
>   PMA_Util::getDocuLink( string 'faq', string 'faq7-2', )
>   ./libraries/display_select_lang.lib.php#59: PMA_Util::showDocu( string
>   'faq', string 'faq7-2', ) ./index.php#231:
>   PMA_getLanguageSelectorHtml() Warning in
>   ./libraries/Util.class.php#516  file_exists(): open_basedir
>   restriction in effect. File(doc/html/index.html) is not within the
>   allowed path(s):
>   (/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/)
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./libraries/Util.class.php#516: file_exists(string
>   'doc/html/index.html') ./index.php#390: PMA_Util::getDocuLink(string
>   'index')  You are using an incomplete translation, please help to make
>   it better by contributing. Warning in ./libraries/Util.class.php#516 
>   file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(doc/html/index.html) is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/)
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./libraries/Util.class.php#516: file_exists(string
>   'doc/html/index.html')
>   ./libraries/navigation/NavigationHeader.class.php#170:
>   PMA_Util::getDocuLink(string 'index')
>   ./libraries/navigation/NavigationHeader.class.php#53:
>   PMA_NavigationHeader->_links()
>   ./libraries/navigation/Navigation.class.php#35:
>   PMA_NavigationHeader->getDisplay() ./libraries/Header.class.php#418:
>   PMA_Navigation->getDisplay() ./libraries/Response.class.php#263:
>   PMA_Header->getDisplay() ./libraries/Response.class.php#276:
>   PMA_Response->_getDisplay() ./libraries/Response.class.php#390:
>   PMA_Response->_htmlResponse() PMA_Response::response()

Comment: How is your phpMyAdmin installed? Using dpkg/apt/aptitude/synaptic or by manually downloading the source? Also, which phpMyAdmin version is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by change the access URL,because before the update i changed to /adminphp and when i have done the update, everything got confused so i changed to the default, /phpmydmin and restarted apache server, and changed again to the same link and errors have disapeared.